# What is different between two codes of for loop?

Tags: c++, reference, auto, range-based-loop

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (auto &x : a)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (auto x : a)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

Two codes above prints same values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
But is there different thing between initializing &x and x?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: the first one is taking by reference, the other one by value. in the first example you could change the elements of `a` through `x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference in the output for the code you wrote. However, if you tried to change the value of `x` when in the loop, there *would* be a difference.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (auto x : a)
        x = 0;
    for (auto x : a)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

is very different to:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (auto & x : a)
        x = 0;

    for (auto x : a)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

In the second, the vector `a` will be all zeros at the end of the program. This is because `auto` by itself copies each element to a temporary value inside the loop, whereas `auto &` takes a *reference* to an element of the vector, which means that if you assign something to the reference it overwrites wherever the reference is pointing.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is really useful.

Comment: Another difference becomes visible if the data type is not a simple int, but some big class. Then making the copy can be *very* expensive ( == slow), while taking only the reference will always be fast.

Comment: @U.W. A nice example to prove it ( maybe ) https://godbolt.org/z/xnnf9Y Replace 'auto' with 'auto &' and the copy goes away. However now I've added the copy constructor by hand does that change the optimizations the compiler is allowed to make? Maybe a trivially copyable object is allowed to optimize away the copy if only const methods are called? How to test?

Comment: Or maybe a better proof without modifying the class constructor. https://godbolt.org/z/qP6bWa Check that the address of the temporary.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing How to test? Well, compile only to the assembly level and look at the code. It's as simple as that! :-)